# Need To Buy Ubuntu DVD 13.04

Tags: 13.04

I need to buy ubuntu 13.04 (or above) DVD, But it is not in the store... Why is that?? And i need to take it via post how can I Do it and.. I need to know the cost. I have some other ubuntu Accessories to buy.. I'am in Sri Lanka

Comment: I would have suggested OnDisc but their [shipping page](http://www.osdisc.com/support/shipping.html) suggests they don't ship to Sri Lanka.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of companies out there who sell printed DVDs of Ubuntu and other distributions, just a "buy ubuntu dvd" in Google away. Some won't ship there, I'd be surprised if you couldn't find any.

But there are few places in the world where you're the only Ubuntu user. I would suggest looking to the local Loco: the [Ubuntu Sri Lankan Team](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SriLankanTeam). Get in contact and explain your problem. I would be surprised if somebody couldn't help you out by either bleeming you out a DVD or putting you in contact with somebody who sells them.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, why don't you just download Ubuntu 13.04?  You can do so by clicking [Here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).  As far as Ubuntu Accessories, you can also get online from the [Ubuntu Shop](http://shop.ubuntu.com/).  I don't know if they ship to Sri Lanka, but you can try.

Comment: I think their point about the Ubuntu Shop is it doesn't stock a DVD of 13.04

Comment: @Oli, the shop is for accessories only, and not the DVD.

Comment: [They sell older versions there](http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17).